# How to refetch properly an API request after an event occurred?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

i'm a react beginner and I'm struggling with the refresh of the components.
In this case, I have a GET request to an API triggering in a useEffect hook with no dependencies on my App.js. Of course, this is working just fine when my app just starts. However, I need it to trigger again after certain events ocurre, like an Onclick event in a button, and a OnSubmit event in a form, in order to re render the updated table component where the API data is displayed.

What is the best way to do this?
I thought about just calling the fetch function again whenever I need to update the data, but I don't know if that's the way to go.
Then, I currently have this workaround function to force the reload of the entire page after the events trigger, but i'm pretty sure this is not proper either:

```
const refresh = () =>{
        window.location.reload(false);
    }
```

I've been also tweaked the dependencies in the use effect (where the fetch happens) a little bit, because I'm feeling like the solution is there, but I had only bad results, like infinite loops.

Finally guys, I'll post an overview pic of my App code. Have in mind that I need to do the refresh in the next components: OrdenPago  y Grid.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { OrdenPago } from './OrdenDePago';
import EstadoCvus from './EstadoCvus';
import Grid from './Grid';
import axios from 'axios';

export const App = () => {    
    const [ops, setOps] = useState({ ordenesPago: [] });       
    
    useEffect( () => {
        axios.get("http://cpawautojava:1400/consultaOrdenesPago")
            .then(response => {
                setOps(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);

            }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) })       
    }, [])        

    return (

        <div className="container">
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='text-white py-2' style={{ backgroundColor: "#414BB2", height: "40px" }} >
                        <h1 className='text-center lead fw-bold'>Gestión de OPs</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
            </div>

            <div className='row mt-3' >
                <div className='col-6 d-flex justify-content-center'>
                    <OrdenPago />
                </div>
                <div className='col-6 form1' >
                    <EstadoCvus />                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className='row'>              
                <div className='col-12' >
                    <Grid ops={ops} />   
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Rodrigo.

Comment: Where is that event happening where you want to make an api call in which component? Can you share that code? And you want to make a same api call that is being made in the `useEffect`?

Comment: hey, that's right. I need to call the same API request as in the useEffect. 
I have to do that both in Grid and in OrdenPago components. I both cases, I need to recall the API from an onClick button event, in order to update the grid.